# Algorithm to convert a collection of edges into collection of triangles

Tags: algorithm, graphics, polygon, computational-geometry, mesh

I have implemented a polygon triangulation algorithm into my program. The algorithm first takes a [simple polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon), described as 2D points/vertices, and splits it into [y-monotone pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_polygon). 
After this is done, the algorithm then takes each monotone polygon piece and splits it into triangular pieces.

The input to the algorithm I need help with is an array of vertices outlining a y-monotonic polygon in clockwise or counter-clockwise order. The output is a collection of all edges, both from the original polygon but also the new ones added by the triangulation algorithm in order to split this y-monotonic piece into triangular pieces. This works great if I only want to paint the result as it's possible to just draw each edge.

However, there is no particular order to this collection of edges, and I need the output to be an array of type [triangle strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip) *or* an array where each triangle is simply described by it's 3 vertices (Example: *[a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3]* as we have triangle *a* and triangle *b*).

Is there any conventional algorithm or any other way which can help me solve this? Speed is not of extreme importance but I'd prefer a fast solution.

Here is a pseudocode example of the program used in order to give a better understanding of my question:

```
class Vertex {
 var point;
 var index;
 init(x,y,index){
   point = (x,y)
   self.index = index
 }
}

class Edge {
 var from; // of type Vertex
 var to; // of type Vertex
 init(from, to){
  self.from = from
  self.to = to
 }
}
```

A call to a function `getMonotonePiecesOfPolygon(polygon)` could generate one of many monotonic polygon pieces that would have these vertices and edges:

```
var vertex0 = Vertex(x0,y0,0)
var vertex1 = Vertex(x1,y1,1)
var vertex2 = Vertex(x2,y2,2)
var vertex3 = Vertex(x3,y3,3)

var edge0 = Edge(vertex0, vertex1)
var edge1 = Edge(vertex1, vertex2)
var edge2 = Edge(vertex2, vertex3)
var edge3 = Edge(vertex3, vertex4)
```

This could correspond to a rectangle like this:

```
         edge0
       0------1
       |      |
 edge3 |      | edge1
       |      |
       3------2 
         edge2
```

Then, we can supply these edges in an array and divide the polygon into triangles with the a triangulation method 'makeMonotonePolygonIntoTrianglePieces()'

```
var edgesArray = [edge0,edge1,edge2,edge3]  
var edgesArray = makePolygonIntoTrianglePieces(edgesArray)
```

Now the `edgesArray` could look like this:

```
edgesArray == [edge0,edge1,edge2,edge3,newEdge1]
```

where

```
newEdge1.from == vertex0
newEdge1.to == vertex2
```

which would correspond to a polygon like this if we were to draw each edge:

```
         edge0
       0------1
       |\     |
 edge3 |  \   | edge1
       |    \ |
       3------2 
         edge2
```

Now here is the part of what my question is seeking to solve. I need an array which would look like this:

```
var triangles = [
                 vertex0,vertex3,vertex2, 
                 vertex0,vertex2,vertex1
                ]
```

or using triangle strips (each triangle described by one new vertex and two vertices from the previous triangle):

```
var triangles = [
                 vertex3, vertex2, vertex0,
                 vertex1
                ]
```

Comment: I don't understand where you're stuck.  You know which edges you've added.  By construction, each of those edges is common to exactly two triangles.  You look for the one or two vertices connected to *both* ends of that edge.  Better yet, keep a list of your constructed triangles as you add the edges.  Then you can sort them as you wish.  If you want a triangle strip, then removed the superfluous elements from your sorted list.

Comment: Maybe I’m just to tired to think but I’m not following what you mean that I’m “looking for the one or two vertices connected to both ends of that edge”. The solution with adding each constructed triangle seems as it might work though, I’ll try it out tomorrow :) thanks

Comment: Okay, try a specific example.  In your posted square, you added edge [0, 2].  You know that this added edge forms two triangles.  Thus, you look for the vertices connected to *both* `0` and `2`.  That gives you the two triangles you show in your array.  If you then start with either isolated vertex -- in only one triangle (it will have exactly two edges -- 1 and 3 are those isolated vertices), you can "walk" your way down the triangle strip.

Comment: @Prune: I think the algorithm is not just restricted to polygons constructed with 4 edges. As soon as you have more I guess it is a bit more complicated, because you have to know which of all 'neighboring' edges you can connect with a new edge to get a triangle that is _inside_ the polygon. Of course for all of them you will construct a triangle (maybe though degenerated), but some of them may lie outside (just think about a polygon that forms a star like shape). Btw. you can even produce such a situation with 4 edges.

Comment: OP has already gone through the algorithm of generating the edges.  The question  is then how to produce the final output organization.  You start with an isolated vertex and its two edges, forming the first triangle for the output.  Now, to make this easier to visualize; remove that triangle from the figure.  Recur on the remaining figure.  In many cases (and all cases with a triangle strip), one or both of that triangle's vertices will be isolated.

Comment: Don't let your triangulation algorithm spit independent edges, then try to recover the triangles. Make the algorithm output the triangles, it has all the information needed.

Comment: I'm using the triangulation algorithm proposed in chapter 3 in [this book](https://people.inf.elte.hu/fekete/algoritmusok_msc/terinfo_geom/konyvek/Computational%20Geometry%20-%20Algorithms%20and%20Applications,%203rd%20Ed.pdf). I can't figure out how the algorithm would give me the triangles when it adds edges. If you read the chapter you would see that the same would happen for the 1st part when constructing the part that makes a polygon into y-monotone pieces... I currently have no way of getting each separate monotone piece

Comment: @A.Claesson: represent the edges by the indexes of the endpoints. If you don't want to let the algorithm output the triangles, at least you can find triples of vertices connected by edges.

Comment: @Yves Daoust, how do you mean "you can find triples of vertices connected by edges"? I represent each edge by the indexes of endpoints, so a collection of edges represent the outline of my polygon where the indices tells me how they are connected. But the new edges that the algorithm adds to the polygon has no index that would help me as far as I can tell.

Comment: @A.Claesson: the new edges are indexed by the points they link !

Comment: I don't understand how I would handle multiple edges going out from the same point? Ex: `edges = [edge0,edge1,edge2,edge3]` is the original polygon, and I can find the previous or next edge from a particular edge by indices. Then I find out that a new edge `edge4` should be drawn between `point2` and `point0` as in the example above. How should the `edges`-array be modified to allow me to find the triangles it makes?

Answer (score 1):

In Chapter 2 of the book you refer to in one of the comments, they present a data structure called Doubly-Connected Edge List (DCEL). DCEL:s are used to store planar subdivisions such as triangulations. From what you write, I think it could be what you are looking for.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list

Comment: I've implemented a regular double linked list to store my edges and represent the polygon. I'm not sure how I would use such a data structure to store the subdivisions when new edges are added from the algorithm. In the original polygon each vertex has one previous vertex and one vertex in front. Eventually the algoritm finds that an edge should be added between two vertices, which would create a triangle. However this would also mean that the vertices that the new edge contains now has 3 edges containing them. How do I store this subdivision?

Comment: Well, I stiil think an DCEL is what you should consider. But if you use lists you could have one node per vertex v and then, in each node, a sublist with pointers to all other vertices u such that there is an edge between v and u (remember to store the edge at both the node of v and the node of u). You might also like to store pointers of a sublist as the edges are ordered around the vertex, well, this of course depends on what you eventually like to do with the triangulation and how important efficiency is.

Comment: Ah ok, I just don’t understand what the difference between storing the edges in a regular double linked list and using DCEL would be?

Comment: The DCEL contains more info like, for instance, what faces exist and how they are located next to each other. A triangulation is a somewhat simple subdivision, so an DCEL might not be needed, but one way or another, you need to maintain pointer chains between the parts of the subdividion (vertices, edges, and faces) and that is exactly what a DCEL keeps consists of. The way you should represent data depends on how you like to use it.

Comment: The alternative I suggested, using lists in lists, would probably work fine in most small-scale cases. Just be careful and maintain order, for instance angular orders of edges around a vertex. With the lists it should, for instance, be rather easy to add a new edge (=pointers between the vertices bounding the edge stored in the sublists of the vertices), although not necessarily very efficient.

Comment: I see, I’ll definitely look into your suggestions more when I have the time, but I put this problem on ice for a while. Thanks!